# How to allow nested accordions but manage top level as accordion (and not collapsable) with materializecss?

Tags: materialize

I'm using nested accordions with `Materializecss`. I want to be able to have nested accordions, but to let each level to only have 1 item of the accordion opened (as of `data-collapsible='accordion'`).

I can't get it to work: if I set `data-collapsible='accordion'` I cannot open nested accordions, and if I set `data-collapsible='collapsible'`, I can open any number of items per accordion.

Any workaround?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you are managing the inner elements of the collapsibles dinamically, then you need to "initialize" them using a jquery method included in "materialize.js". This is written in the "materializecss" documentation [here](http://materializecss.com/collapsible.html#intialization).

I'll provide a practical example.

Given the next HTML:

```html
    ...
        <ul class="collapsible" data-collapsible="accordion">
          <li>
          <div class="collapsible-header">
            My nested collapsible
          </div>
          <div class="collapsible-body">
            <ul class="nested collapsible" data-collapsible="accordion">
              <!-- No data initially -->
            </ul>
          </div>
          </li>
        <li>
          <div class="collapsible-header">Second</div>
          <div class="collapsible-body">
            <p>Normal data...</p>
          </div>
        </li>
        
        </ul>
    ...
```

I suppose the problem comes because you are appending data into the ".nested" div, and it's not working as an accordion as expected.

You should then do something like:

```js
// ... Your handler code ...
// ... Data appended into $('.nested')
$('.nested').collapsible({accordion: true});
// ...
```

The {accordion: true} option is not mandatory, as it will be treated as an accordion by default.

It should work in this case. Good luck.